# How to wire GFCI combination switch/receptacle

Tags: wiring, receptacle, gfci

I’ve looked all over and I can’t seem to find any diagrams for this specific application.

I have a combo switch/outlet GFCI receptacle that is midstream on the circuit and I want to wire it so that the switch controls the outlet that is part of the receptacle, and so that the downstream outlets receive power and are also GFCI protected.

I’ve only been able to find diagrams where the combo switch/outlet is at the end of the run, or where the combo receptacle has constant power to the outlet and the switch toggles a nearby overhead light.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm...frankly not sure if that's possible, since the receptacle terminals are not broken out separately from the GFCI function on such a combination device, at least as far as I know...

Comment: Is replacing the box at this location an option?

Comment: Yes it’s on back porch and I have the entire box out, loose, and broken down

Comment: Where is the box that supplies power to this located at?

Comment: I am with @ThreePhaseEel. I don't think the device allows what you want to do. Why don't you just install a GFCI breaker or an upstream GFCI Device and be done with it?

Comment: The reason is because we have a strand of outdoor lights that plugs in at this location that we want controlled by a switch within the same single gang receptacle.  I  pigtailed past the first outdoor receptacle on this circuit because it is in an inconvenient location to reset if the thing trips. This combo receptacle is the first GFI receptacle with in the porch area so I guess I just thought it would be easier if this combo receptacle was responsible for the downstream protection

Comment: ThreePhaseEel, this is the second outlet in a circuit with five outlets (ending with a porch ceiling fan that will be controlled by a switch). I have one GFCI upstream that I bypassed in order to put the burden of protection starting with this combo receptacle in position 2. Since the first and second are both GFCI on their own, I suppose I could pass the burden of protection to a GFCI receptacle in the 3rd position? At that rate, I’m still not positive on the best way to wire the combo receptacle in position 2. I’m pretty sure that the combo switch controls anything plugged into the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it figured out with the help of my electrician friend...

Pigtail hot inbound and outbound wires with one of the hot wires protruding from back of the combo switch. Send the 2nd hot wire protruding from from of the combo switch to LINE brass/hot side.

Take neutral inbound and outbound wires and pigtail to LINE silver/neutral side.

Obviously connect the grounds together.

I now have the combo switch operating it’s own outlet and have allowed for power to continue on to the next outlet downstream, though of course passing the burden of GFI protection to the next outlet.